# Recurrent job with ReactJS -> Express or better with Express -> ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, express, cron, frontend, backend

**What do I have:**

- I have a ReactJS app that when I visit it, it process some files, show me the results, connects to Express and Express then saves the data to a file

**What I want to do:**

- Apart from visiting the web anytime I want, I want it to be "visited" every day at a certain hour, so that the files are processed and saved

**How can I do this?**

- Option 1 (is it possible?), make Express to call some function in the React app with cron-schedule so that the same process is initiated and executed
- Option 2, programm everything on the server side, and re-make the React app not to process anything but simply to show the results that the server has processed

What would be the best choice? Option 1 would be the fastest, but is it doable?

Comment: Option 1? Doing this with your own website is weird. It's as simple as using headless browser like Nightmare or Puppeteer. There should be no problems with Option 2 if you have code that can be easily reused on server side.

Comment: This is what I'm trying now, just wondering what's the usual way to do this. I guess using this "headless browser" strategy (thanks for the key words! I'm gonna take a look) is not the most elegant solution

Comment: Option 2 is usual. Option 1 is a workaround.